# MYSQL - where com relacionamento não retonam resultado

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Preciso usar esse where em uma query, mas sem sucesso

Com 'AND' não funciona.

```
    where ((`atributos_detalhes`.`keyValue` = 'dormitorios' and `relation_imovel_detalhes`.`value` in (2)) **AND**
(`atributos_detalhes`.`keyValue` = 'areaTerreno' and `relation_imovel_detalhes`.`value` > 0))
```

Assim ele funciona com "or" entre eles, mas não como gostaria

```
where ((`atributos_detalhes`.`keyValue` = 'dormitorios' and `relation_imovel_detalhes`.`value` in (2)) **OR**
    (`atributos_detalhes`.`keyValue` = 'areaTerreno' and `relation_imovel_detalhes`.`value` > 0))
```

Comment: Meu amigo: você tem que saber um mínimo de lógica para saber se o que deseja é construir sua expressão utilizando os conectores lógicos AND ou OR. Não tem o menor sentido você ficar substituindo um pelo outro sem saber o por quê.

Comment: Eu entendo os operadores logicos, a questão é que preciso usar o AND, mas o end não funciona, consigo usar o OR, mas não como seria o AND. Então gostaria de uma forma pra que isso seja possível. Como está descrito nos códigos. Obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: provavelmente não é que não funciona, mas todas as condições juntas não devem ocorrer

Comment: Você começa seu comentário com "Eu entendo os operadores logicos" mas o que você coloca a seguir dá a entender o contrário. Sem você descrever o que pretende obter ninguém pode opinar sobre qual das duas expressões que você postou está correta ou até se ambas estão erradas.

Comment: Não faz sentido, no primeiro parênteses você tem `keyValue = 'dormitorios'`, e no segundo `keyValue = 'areaTerreno'`, nunca ambas as verificações vão retornar verdadeiro, ou é um ou é outro. Se quiser ajuda, explique o que são cada campo, mostre a estrutura da tabela e exemplique a saída que deseja

Answer (score 0):

Você construiu uma expressão que deseja que um atributo (`keyValue`) tenha dois valores, o que não será possível.

`keyValue` = 'dormitorios' E `keyValue` = 'areaTerreno'